# JavaScript checking the background color of a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple program where you can select a color and fill a box with it. I have a 4x4 grid of boxes(divs) and I want to check if the backgroundColor of all the divs(boxes) has a value, so that when all the boxes are filled with a color the grid resets and all the boxes are blank again.

However, I am having some problems implementing this. My first idea was to check that every div in the array (I've used querySelectorAll) has a backgroundColor 'red' or 'blue'. I've tried to store the backgroundColor of the array item into a variable but that doesn't return the string when I console log it.

I also tried the every() method on the Array but that didn't seem to work.

So my question would be, how do I get the backgroundColor of an element in a nodelist and check to see if that element has a backgroundColor.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
var redColor = document.getElementById('red');
var blueColor = document.getElementById('blue');
var box = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
var colorPick = document.getElementById('color picker');


let currentColor = [];
Array.from(box);
console.log(box);

loadEventListeners();

function loadEventListeners(){

  redColor.addEventListener('click', pickRed);
  blueColor.addEventListener('click', pickBlue);
  for (i = 0; i < box.length; i++){
    box[i].addEventListener('click', addColor);
  }
};


function pickRed(e){

  currentColor.push('red');
  var textRed = document.createTextNode("You have selected red");
  colorPick.appendChild(textRed);
  console.log(currentColor);
}

function pickBlue(e){
  currentColor.push('blue')
  console.log(currentColor);
}


function addColor(e){

  if (currentColor.slice(-1)[0] === 'blue'){
    e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'blue'; 
  } else { e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'red'; 

  }

}
```

And here is the HTML I'm using:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.container{

  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 200px;
  display: grid;
  align-items: auto;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}


.game-grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
  margin: 0;
}

#color-picker{
  display: grid;

  grid-template-rows: 100px 50px 50px;

}

.box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 2px;
}

#red{
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="game-grid">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
      <div id="color picker">
        <h2>Pick a color!</h2>
          <div id="red"></div>
          <div id="blue"></div>
          <div id="green"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `Array.from(box);` does not do what you think it does. It returns a new array and you are not storing it. It does not change box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `querySelectorAll` is not a complete array. It is more like an "array like" object. But it does not support `every` (or `forEach`, or `map` ...).

But you can make it a real array with `Array.from`.

But in your code you only do `Array.from(box);`. But this code does nothing because box will not be modified. You have to write `box = Array.from(box);` or use it directly:

```
Array.from(box).every(function(div) {
    return div.style.backgroundColor == 'blue' || div.style.backgroundColor == 'red';
});
```

Comment: well you missed the line where OP uses Array from, but the wrong way.

Comment: Thank you! This was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the background color of an element with `getComputedStyle`. To get the background color of many nodes inside a nodelist, you can convert the nodelist to a real array with `Array.from` and then use `Array.prototype.every`.

Example shows how to use `getComputedStyle` as well as `Array.from`.

```js
const queryAll = (selector, node = document) => Array.from(node.querySelectorAll(selector));

const getComputedBG = node => window.getComputedStyle(node, null).getPropertyValue('background-color');



const $msgNode = document.querySelector('.msg');

const onClick = e => {
  $msgNode.textContent = getComputedBG(e.target);
}

queryAll('.box').forEach(node => {
  node.addEventListener('click', onClick);
});
```

```css
.list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 200px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.box {
  background: #000;
}
.box--color1 {
  background: #c00;
}
.box--color2 {
  background: #00c;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="box box--color1"></div>
  <div class="box box--color1"></div>
  <div class="box box--color2"></div>
  <div class="box box--color1"></div>
  <div class="box box--color2"></div>
  <div class="box box--color2"></div>
</div>
<div class="msg"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you were almost good, but I think that you did not spend too much time trying to design the behavior. I am not 100% up to date for querySelector, but you can use getElementByClassName too, it will give you an array of HTMLelement.

First, for the color selection, I won't push elements in an Array, but simply udpate one string variable I would call **myCurrentColor**.

Then I would have my redColor function that changes myCurrentColor to red, and same thing for the blue.

Finally for the part where you stuck, I would keep your addColor but it would look like this :

```
addColor(htmlEl) {
 if(htmlEl.style.backgroundColor != 'blue' || htmlEl.style.backgroundColor != 'red') {
   htmlEl.style.backgroundColor = myCurrentColor;
 } else {
    return;
 }
}
```

Example : https://codepen.io/andrea06590/pen/WLzvpE

Comment: background color does not typically return not the name of the color in most browsers.

Comment: I have never heard about this problem. Have you tried using Javascript instead as I recommended ?

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList, which is not an Array. It does not have all the spiffy array methods like `map` or `filter`. However, you can convert it to an array by doing either:

```
let arr = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.box'))
```

or

```
let arr = [...document.querySelectorAll('.box')]
```

Once you've got your array, you can, for example, let `filter` loose on it:

```
arr.filter(b => {
  let bg = b.style.backgroundColor;
  return bg === 'red' || bg === 'blue';
});
```

and that would get you an array of all boxes that have a background color set.

Comment: I didn't know about filter() - Can I wrap this in an if statement to check if all the divs are colored and then invoke a function that clears their background colors?

Comment: Sure, check that the returned array is not empty, then call `.each` on it to clear each box.